# Msg 137, Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @SKUCode1 varchar(30), @SKUCode2 varchar(30), @SKUCode3 varchar(30),
        @SKUCode4 varchar(30), @SKUCode5 varchar(30), @SKUCode6 varchar(30),
        @SKUCode7 varchar(30), @SKUCode7 varchar(30), @SKUCode8 varchar(30),
        @SKUCode10 varchar(30), @Temp_SKU varchar(30), @SKUCodeS varchar(30),
        @sp1 nvarchar(max),@Index int

Set @SKUCodeS = 'SKUCode'
Set @Index = 0

While @Index < 10   
Begin
    Set @Index = @Index + 1  

    Select @Temp_SKU = SKUCode  
    From dbo.UDA_Order  
    Where Areaname = 'LMC-TYRE BUILDING'

    Set @sp1 = 'Set'+' '+ @SKUCodeS+CONVERT(varchar,@Index)+' '+'='+' '+'@Temp_SKU'  

    Exec sp_executesql @sp1  
End
```

This is throwing error

> Msg 137,Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@Temp_SKU"

I have no clue why it is happening.

Please help.

Comment: Variables are local to a particular *scope*. `Exec` runs code in a *new* scope. You can't achieve what you're trying to do here with these variables. What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: There are other issues here also - which may just be due to you simplifying the code before posting - but which also raise red flags - e.g. the `SELECT` to set `@Temp_SKU` doesn't seem to depend on the loop in any way. If there's only a single row matching the `WHERE` clause then it's redundant to do it in a loop. If there are multiple rows, there's no guarantee on which row(s) values will be used to fulfil the assignment each time. One row *could* be used all ten times, but that's by no means guaranteed, and probably not the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I want to get the values for parameters "@SKUCode1" to "@SKUCode10", at each execution of the loop the value in "@Temp_SKU" should move in "@SKUCodeX" where X is the loop index

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the first task - assign appropriate values to each variable, can be done like this:

```
--Sample data
declare @t table (SKUCode varchar(30) not null,MachineNo int not null)
insert into @t(SKUCode,MachineNo) values
('abc',1),
('def',2),
('ghi',3),
('jkl',4),
('mno',5),
('pqr',6),
('stu',7),
('vwx',8),
('uzA',9),
('BCD',10)

--Actual query
Declare @SKUCode1 varchar(30), @SKUCode2 varchar(30), @SKUCode3 varchar(30),
        @SKUCode4 varchar(30), @SKUCode5 varchar(30), @SKUCode6 varchar(30),
        @SKUCode7 varchar(30), @SKUCode8 varchar(30), @SKUCode9 varchar(30),
        @SKUCode10 varchar(30)

select @SKUCode1 = [1], @SKUCode2 = [2], @SKUCode3 = [3],
       @SKUCode4 = [4], @SKUCode5 = [5], @SKUCode6 = [6],
       @SKUCode7 = [7], @SKUCode8 = [8], @SKUCode9 = [9],
       @SKUCode10 = [10]
from (select * from @t pivot (MAX(SKUCode) for
      MachineNo in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])) u
      where 1=1 --Areaname, couldn't be bothered to include it here
      ) t

select @SKUCode5
```

Which prints `mno`, as it should. And we've avoided any nasty loops, dynamic SQL, etc.

Whether the *next* part of your problem is now easily solved, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks ...This is the only solution which worked, previous solution which I was trying was not possible because I was trying to pass the local parameters to the global. I was trying to save the length of code but its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You add `@Temp_SKU` to the string that gets executed dynamically. However, sp_execute is unaware of your context and doesn't have a reference to `@TEMP_SKU`. Try adding the value of `@Temp_SKU` in stead of a refecence to the variable by removing the quotes:

```
 Set @sp1 = 'Set'+' '+ @SKUCodeS+CONVERT(varchar,@Index)+' '+'='+' '+ @Temp_SKU
```

Try `print`ing `@sp1` before the call to `sp_execute` to see what actually gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You're using @Temp_SKU in the dynamic query. When the dynamic query is fired you have to declare it in the scope of the dynamic query, I'd advise using a different name:

```
Set @sp1 = 'Set'+' '+ @SKUCodeS+CONVERT(varchar,@Index)+' '+'='+' '+'@Temp_SKUDYN'  
Exec sp_executesql @sp1  N'@Temp_SKUDYN varchar(30)' @Temp_SKUDYN = @@Temp_SKU
```

However, what are you actually trying to do? It looks like you're trying to set a local variable dynamically. In that case you have to use something like:

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @IntVariable INT
DECLARE @Lastlname varchar(30)
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @LastlnameOUT = max(lname)
                   FROM pubs.dbo.employee WHERE job_lvl = @level'
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@level tinyint,
                        @LastlnameOUT varchar(30) OUTPUT'
SET @IntVariable = 35
EXECUTE sp_executesql
@SQLString,
@ParmDefinition,
@level = @IntVariable,
@LastlnameOUT=@Lastlname OUTPUT
SELECT @Lastlname
```

(Copied from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262499))

**EDIT**

Not at all sure now this will be a solution for you. Better you explain what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

**EDIT 2**

I still think it could be easier, but this is at least clearer (untested, may need some work):

```
Declare @SKUCode1 varchar(30), @SKUCode2 varchar(30), @SKUCode3 varchar(30),
        @SKUCode4 varchar(30), @SKUCode5 varchar(30), @SKUCode6 varchar(30),
        @SKUCode7 varchar(30), @SKUCode8 varchar(30), @SKUCode9 varchar(30),
        @SKUCode10 varchar(30), @Temp_SKU varchar(30), @SKUCodeS varchar(30),
        @sp1 nvarchar(max),@Index int

CREATE TABLE ##codes (i INT, Val VARCHAR(30))
;

Set @SKUCodeS = 'SKUCode'
Set @Index = 0

While @Index < 10   
Begin
    Set @Index = @Index + 1  

    Select @Temp_SKU = SKUCode  
    From dbo.UDA_Order  
    Where Areaname = 'LMC-TYRE BUILDING'
        AND MachineNumber = @Index

    Set @sp1 = 'insert into ##codes(i, Val) VALUES('+ @Index + ',' + @Temp_SKU + ' )'-- 'Set'+' '+ @SKUCodeS+CONVERT(varchar,@Index)+' '+'='+' '+'@Temp_SKU'  

    Exec sp_executesql @sp1  
END

SELECT      @SKUCode1 = 1
,           @SKUCode2 = 2
,           @SKUCode3 = 3
,           @SKUCode4 = 4
,           @SKUCode5 = 5
,           @SKUCode6 = 6
,           @SKUCode7 = 7
,           @SKUCode8 = 8
,           @SKUCode9 = 9
,           @SKUCode10 = 10
FROM        (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    ##codes AS C
                PIVOT   (
                            MAX(VAL)
                            FOR i IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
                        ) p
            ) piv

DROP TABLE ##codes
```

Comment: I am trying to get the values for SKUCode1 to SKUCode10, after getting there values these values will be passed to the machine controller.That's why I am using dynamic query.One thing which I missed to mention that  "Where Areaname = 'LMC-TYRE BUILDING' AND MachineNumber = @Index"

Comment: In the solution provided by you I need "@LastnameOUT" as a variable,Whose value should change from "@SKUCode1" to "@SKUCode10"

Comment: Yeah, I think you should be able to use the second code block. I do think however, there must be an easier way. Not sure what yet, though

Comment: You can pivot directly from `UDA_Order`. There's no need to loop, use dynamic SQL, use a temp table, etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, oh yeah, looks like you're right. Got stuck in a thinking pattern...